# Assigning Cell Value Based on Multi-Level String Comparison

Tags: excel, vba

Short and sweet: I have a very large data set and I am trying to assign a sales territory to each entry. The sales territory depends on two values 1) the state and 2) the county. For all states **EXCEPT** WV, KY, and TN the sales territory can be assigned based only on the state value. For WV, KY, and TN the sales territory is based on both the state and county value. For these three states certain counties belong to differing sales territories.

Here are screenshots of a sample data set before and after I run my code:

[DataSet_Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYEU0.png)

[DataSet_After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Krc9Y.png)

My code identifies the STATE column and county (named FIPS_CNTY_NM) column, then inserts a new column next to the county column called "TERRITORY" where I want the sales territories to be assigned.

```
Sub assignTerritory()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim countyName As String
Dim countyColumn As Long
Dim stateName As String
Dim stateColumn As Long
Dim stateValue As String
Dim countyValue As String
Dim i As Long

Set WS = Worksheets("Data")

With WS
    
    
    'Find numeric last row used on sheet
    lastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Range("A1"), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row
        
    MsgBox "The last row with entered data is " & lastRow
    
    
    'Find state column
    stateName = "STATE"

    stateColumn = .Rows(1).Find(What:=stateName, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column

    MsgBox "The " & stateName & " header is found in column " & stateColumn

    
    'Find county column
    countyName = "FIPS_CNTY_NM"

    countyColumn = .Rows(1).Find(What:=countyName, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column

    MsgBox "The " & countyName & " header is found in column " & countyColumn
    
    
    'Insert a row to the right of the county column
    .Columns(countyColumn + 1).Insert Shift:=xlToLeft, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeft
    
    
    'Give new column header "TERRITORY"
    .Cells(1, countyColumn + 1).Value = "TERRITORY"
    
    
    'Assign territory
    For i = 2 To lastRow
    
        stateValue = Trim(.Cells(i, stateColumn).Value)
        countyValue = Trim(.Cells(i, countyColumn).Value)
        
        If StrComp("PA", stateValue, vbTextCompare) Then .Cells(i, countyColumn + 1).Value = "Northern Appalachian"
        
        Next i
        
End With

End Sub
```

I am not sure of the best way to tackle my string comparison for multiple values. My first attempt was to tackle a state I know that I will only use the state value to assign the territory in this case, PA. I use the StrComp function but as you can see from the DataSet_After, my code is assigning the value I want ("Northern Appalachia") to every state but PA. I am not sure why this is happening. I don't know if its in my statement after Then or what as I have tried things like changing the .Cells to .Range and assigning a cell, but I end up with the same result.

The data set includes the sales territories by state but not by county. For anyone who may be able to help (and I can hopefully extrapolate to my other cases) if the state value is PA, OH, MD, ME, NY, VT, DE, NJ, CT, NH, RI, or MA the TERRITORY should be assigned "Northern Appalachia." If the state is WV **AND** the county (FIPS_CNTY_NM) is equal to any of these:

[Hancock, Brooke, Ohio, Marshall, Wetzel, Monongalia, Preston, Marion, Wood, Pleasants, Tyler, Wirt, Ritchie, Dodd-Ridge, Harrison, Gilmer, Lewis, Taylor, Barbour, Upshur, Tucker, Randolph, Pendleton, Grant, Mineral, Hampshire, Hardy, Morgan, Berkeley, Jefferson]

then the sales territory should be assigned "Northern Appalachia." If the state is WV and the county (FIPS_CNTY_NM) **IS NOT** equal to any of those listed above the sales territory should be "Central Appalachia."

How could I accomplish this?

I just started learning VBA about 2 months ago for this project and have many other responsibilities at work so I have not been able to completely dive into learning VBA as best as possible. I am not a software developer so picking up on basics is slower than normal but this community has been a great help so far so I look forward to reading any answers!

Comment: thanks @BigBen I will be sure to go back and do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple layers of select case will help you.

```
  For i = 2 To lastRow

        stateValue = Trim(.Cells(i, stateColumn).Value)
        countyValue = Trim(.Cells(i, countyColumn).Value)

        Dim terr as String

        Select Case stateValue

            Case "PA","OH","MD","ME","NY","VT","DE","NJ","CT","NH","RI","MA"

                terr = "Northern Appalachian"

            Case "WV"

                 Select Case countyValue
                    Case "Hancock","Brooke","Ohio" ' keep adding
                        terr = "Northern Appalachian"
                    Case Else
                        terr = "Central Appalachian"
                 End Select

         End Select

   .Cells(i, countyColumn + 1).Value = terr

Next i
```

Comment: this looks awesome @scott holtzman. So basically I would continue adding cases for the other states? It seems simple enough. I did take a java class last year for fun to start learning how to code on the side and I vaguely remember using cases for the outcome of a randomized rock, paper, scissors game we had to build. Funny how some things you learn become useful one day...

Comment: Case statements are an invaluable tool that I use very often @ekko. Yes, you can keep adding case statements as needed, but sometimes a simple `IF` may work better  (cleaner code and more readable).

Comment: I was able to perfectly accomplish my goal with the case statement. I also added a case for anything outside my list that was given the value "Not assigned." 90,000 entries only took a few seconds to run through. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In your worksheet the association between State and Territory is made by cell color. Therefore your code should look for the cell color in the State column and pick the Territory name from a cell of identical color in the Key list.

I don't like color based sorting but if it works for you that's fine. The alternative is a 2-column Key in which you associate each Territory with States or Counties. The second column in the Key list would contain strings like "PA, NY, Hancock, NJ". The code would look at the County column of each row and use the county name if one exists, else switching to the State column. Either value is looked for in the strings of the Key table's second column and the Territory returned from the row where a match was found.

Comment: Hello again @Variatus! I actually color coded the example just to help anyone reading my question understand more easily. My actual values exist just as text in a white cell. To follow up on your response, every ID has both a state and county, not just some. I figured from a handling perspective I could accomplish my goal using code that examined only the state when needed and then both state and county when needed. I'm definitely not an expert but I thought when it would only look at one value rather than both I could maximize the speed. I do have almost 90,000 values to assign

Comment: If every row has both State and County your examples are misleading. However, the key is the Key table. It must have two columns and the method of coding I described above will work either way. Adding an extra step to process WV, KY and TN by looking for Counties and all others for States would probably be faster.